# How to run Starlink Android app on PC via emulator/VM?

Tags: applications, android-emulator, virtualization

Has anyone successfully run the [Starlink](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.starlink.mobile) Android app on a PC via an emulator or VM?

I know of accessing the web GUI of Starlink by URL with `http://dishy.starlink.com/` or `192.168.100.1`. However, a lot of features are not available unless configured via the app. In some windows, parts are greyed out with a message stating *Edit these settings using the Starlink mobile application for iOS or Android*

[image]

I have attempted so far with Windows 10 to run Starlink on emulators suggested from [here](https://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-emulators-for-pc-655308/) such as BlueStacks, MeMU Play, NoxPlayer, and Android Emulator with Android Studio. I have also attempted to run Android x86 with the steps provided [here](https://www.partitionwizard.com/resizepartition/android-virtualbox.html), but still no success. Each try, the app attempts to load, but then crashes and never fully loads.

I should add that the Starlink app does not appear in my search when I try to find it on an Android Studio emulator with the Google Play Store enabled.

[image]

This [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232977/371737) that I found leads me to believe there is some kind of check to determine whether it is being loaded on an emulator.

My current specs for my Win10 PC are the following:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.19045 N/A Build 19045
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
System Manufacturer:       Dell Inc.
System Model:              Precision 5560
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11850H @ 2.50GHz   2.50 GHz
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 141 Stepping 1 GenuineIntel ~2496 Mhz
BIOS Version:              Dell Inc. 1.19.0, 3/10/2023
Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Total Physical Memory:     32,492 MB
Available Physical Memory: 12,525 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  65,260 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 29,946 MB
```

Is it possible that the Starlink app simply cannot be run via an emulator or VM due to technical limitations?

---

**EDIT:**

As suggested in the comments, I side loaded the [Starlink app](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/space-exploration-technologies-corp/starlink/starlink-2023-17-0-release/starlink-2023-17-0-android-apk-download/#file) on the android emulator, and I also had crashes. In an attempt that took less than 5 seconds, I only extracted error messages that seem to relate to the Starlink app crash from `Logcat` from android studio to avoid bloat (here is a [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/fvKiwdju) for full log):

```
2023-06-13 10:43:18.323  9504-9504  SoLoader                pid-9504                               E  couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so
                                                                                                        SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~qoOC8gBYQvkgf0PRhrZKRQ==/com.starlink.mobile-LPC2LUqn-Tbl-QKGoc-Jtw==/lib/x86 flags = 0]
                                                                                                        SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectApkSoSource[root = (/data/app/~~qoOC8gBYQvkgf0PRhrZKRQ==/com.starlink.mobile-LPC2LUqn-Tbl-QKGoc-Jtw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, )]
                                                                                                        SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib flags = 2]
                                                                                                        SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib flags = 2]
                                                                                                        Native lib dir: /data/app/~~qoOC8gBYQvkgf0PRhrZKRQ==/com.starlink.mobile-LPC2LUqn-Tbl-QKGoc-Jtw==/lib/x86
                                                                                                       result: 0
.
.
.
2023-06-13 10:43:20.773  9504-9557  Manish                  pid-9504                               E  createNativeModules
.
.
.
2023-06-13 10:43:20.817  9504-9557  AndroidRuntime          pid-9504                               E  FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
                                                                                                      Process: com.starlink.mobile, PID: 9504
                                                                                                      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libviro_renderer.so" not found
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
                                                                                                        at com.viromedia.bridge.module.MaterialManager.<clinit>(MaterialManager.java:58)
                                                                                                        at com.viromedia.bridge.ReactViroPackage.createNativeModules(ReactViroPackage.java:111)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactPackageHelper.getNativeModuleIterator(ReactPackageHelper.java:42)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.processPackage(NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.java:42)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:1456)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackages(ReactInstanceManager.java:1427)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1338)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1200(ReactInstanceManager.java:135)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1109)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

It looks like there was a fatal crash when attempting to find `libviro_renderer.so`.

For those who would like to attempt to recreate this error, drag the apk to the emulator and wait for it to install. Once installed click on the starlink and you should see it display its splash screen and promptly crash/disappear.

Current emulator specs:

```
Emulator Version: 31.3.13-9189900
Android Version: 11.0 (R) - API 30
AVD Configuration: Nexus_5X_API_30
Host Machine: Windows 10 Pro
```

---

**EDIT2:**
Regarding a different suggested comment from Ramhound, the Android subsystem for Windows 11 also had trouble launching the app.
[image]
I will try and follow Andrew's [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/252000/how-to-run-starlink-android-app-on-pc-via-emulator-vm#comment340772_252000) with a specific ARM-based image within Android Studio soon.

Comment: Have you tried running it within WSA on Windows 11? Viewing the web GUI should worked on any operating system provided the device can reach the Starlink terminal on your network

Comment: @Ramhound  unfortunately I do not have access to a system with Windows 11, since I am either running on Windows 10 or Linux.

Comment: The app contains libraries for all platform (x86 and ARM both 32 and 64 bit) therefore it is not limited. But it requires Open GL ES 3.0. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44117381/150978) the Android Studio emulator can support that if your graphics driver is supported. What I don't know is if the app simply checks if it is running on an Emulator and then behaves differently.

Comment: @kyrlon - You should be able to download a free trial Windows 11 VM directly from Microsoft, enable WSA within the VM, to see if the application will even run within WSA.

Comment: @Ramhound That is a suggestion that I might have to try later. Ideally I was hoping for an OS agnostic approach w/ a VM rather than dependent on a specific feature the OS provides.

Comment: @kyrlon - You have attempted the only two other methods to run Android applications within Linux or Windows, through a hypervisor like BlueStacks or through Android X86 within a Virtual Machine and you have indicated both those methods DO NOT work. Which leaves you WSA, or accepting the fact, the application cannot run in those environments.

Comment: @Robert you can see my update adds a link to a post that mentions some apps are not present in the emulator store. I might have to come to terms that the app is not capable to run on emulators.

Comment: What is visible in Play Store or not does not tell you anything about if it will work. Just grab the APK from somewhere else and install it. Then you will see if it work or not.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. "*Each try, the app attempts to load, but then crashes and never fully loads.*" you may consider [checking the log](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/44325) to possibly see the exact reason why it crashed.

Comment: After checking the content of the APK by opening it as a ZIP file, looks like `libjscexecutor.so` is missing on all architectures (related report on [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32928#issuecomment-1017467755))? However, `libviro_renderer.so` is also missing on x86, which is the default installation image, so maybe try with [an ARM-based image](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/247963/44325) instead.